# update repositories

Tags: updates

I want to update the repositories and I see these commands.

```
dpkg: error al procesar el paquete grub-pc (--configure):
 instalado grub-pc paquete post-installation guión el subproceso devolvió un error con estado de salida 128
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depende de grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; sin embargo:
  El paquete `grub-efi-amd64' no está instalado.
 El paquete `grub-pc' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
dpkg: problemas de dependencias impiden la configuración de grub-gfxpayload-lists:
 grub-gfxpayload-lists depende de grub-pc (>= 1.99~20101210-1ubuntu2); sin embargo:
 El paquete `grub-pc' no está configurado todavía.

dpkg: error al procesar el paquete grub-gfxpayload-lists (--configure):
 problemas de dependencias - se deja sin configurar
Procesando disparadores para libc-bin (2.27-3ubuntu1) ...
Se encontraron errores al procesar:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
 grub-gfxpayload-lists
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

What I do??

Comment: Please do not mind me asking, can you change your language to English for a moment and try doing what you want to do in terminal? This way generated error will be in English.

Answer (score 0):

I want to update the repositories and I see these commands.

Setting up grub-pc (2.02-2ubuntu8.13+elementary8~ubuntu5.0.1) ...
dpkg: error processing package grub-pc (--configure):
installed grub-pc package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 128
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
 grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
  Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed.
  Package grub-pc is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 grub-pc
 grub-efi-amd64-signed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

What I do?

Comment: Your machine says "Package grub-efi-amd64 is not installed" (and probably therefore "grub-pc is not configured yet"). Have you tried to install this package?

Answer (score 0):

Type in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
sudo dpkg –configure -a
sudo apt-get install -f
```